# Assign a Specific Value for Every Character in a Cell and Sum the Values in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to create a unique ID based on the value of a string in a cell by assigning every character a value and then summing the values of the characters in the cell to get a number.

For example if A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4; the cell containing ABBCD would be 1+2+2+3+4, and the sum would end up being 12. So the value of that cell would be 12. What is the easiest way to do this in excel?

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far?

Comment: This will not result in unique ID numbers as `ABBCD` will result in a total of `12` but so will `AABDD` (`1 + 1 + 2 + 4 + 4`)

Comment: how about 65+66+66+67+68 ?

Comment: Can easily be done with a formula.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad This is an oversimplified example, as the actual cells contain between 15-100 characters with 68 possible values for each character.

Comment: Sure, but the question is, do you need a unique ID for each possible input string, or are you OK with the possibility of two different strings producing the same ID? Those two questions will have very different answers.

Comment: If you cannont leverage the ASCII value from the characters to create a simple formula you will need to create a two dimensional array that will equate each character with the desired value then loop the string and do some sort of lookup.

Comment: I think that we are missing something.  I do not believe you can achieve your goals as stated with the technique you are suggesting so I am wondering what I am missing. Even if there are 100 characters if the first 98 are the same and the last two characters of one is AB and the last two of another is BA, you will get the same number. You have also not really stated whether the 100 characters are or are not unique. For example, if you get two identical sets of characters, do these get the same "unique" ID or a different "unique" ID?  Is the original set of characters themselves unique?

Comment: @FocusWiz Identical combinations should return the same value. In my particular usecase, it would not be realistic to get the same number value for the cells. Fundamentally, I'm trying to associate each string of text with a number that will ultimately be grouped and separated by this number. I apologize for the lack of clarity.

Comment: So "ABCD#$" AND "ABCD#$" are unlikely to both exist but should have the same unique code, but that code should be different from any other combination of those letters and symbols (e.g. "DCBA#$" would be different and also different from "ABCD$#").  I assume there is some reason why the original values cannot be used.  Will all of the characters be ascii?

Comment: @focuswiz that is correct. The original values can’t be used because because of the significant differences in length and characters of the strings. The characters will be ascii and I’ve considered using the code function, but I’m not sure how to apply it to all of the characters in the strong instead of just the first. However I’m also trying to avoid having different values for uppercase/lowercase letters.

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(CODE(MID(UPPER(A1)&REPT("@",100),ROW(1:100),1))-64)`

Comment: @ScottCraner I wish I had thought of using SUMPRODUCT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that this is not a solution of any kind, but if you are trying to simply assign the numbers to letters and sum them, it is not a particularly complicated issue.  Hopefully, by my giving this answer and us discussing how it does or does not meet your needs, we can figure out what the best alternative will be.  Here is a formula that assigns 1 to "A" 2 to "B" etc and sums them when they appear in a string.  I do not know if it handles the other 16 characters that may be in the original strings, but hopefully it will.

```
=SUM(CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))-64)
```

This is an array formula.

[image]

Since I am updating this, I might add that Scott Craner's comment offers a formula that is not an array formula which would make it less problematic.

---

### modifications

The above was intended to be a half-thought-out straw man since there is nothing in it to avoid duplication of values and it really was not tested significantly.  However, to make it a bit more forgiving and to treat spaces and other characters that might be part of the original code,  I would make some changes.

I would start by first replacing SUM with SUMPRODUCT as so that this is not an array formula as Scott Craner suggested.  The original formula treats all spaces as -32, but I think we probably would want to always increase the value rather than have some characters increase it and others decrease it.  Hence, I am changing it to only adjust the ASCII code for letters of the alphabet.

What I am proposing below is that for the alphabet, we give them the values of 1 to 26 by subtracting 64 from their values.  Then, for the non-alphabetic characters, I would suggest retaining their actual ASCII code.

This formula does that:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)))-SUMPRODUCT((CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<91)*(CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>64)*64)
```

What it does is it starts with the sum of all ASCII values and then subtracts 64 only for those characters which are from "A" to "Z" inclusive.  (A is ASCII 65 and Z is ASCII 90.) Since the ASCII characters from 1 to 26 are generally control codes, this should not overlap any actual characters that may be encountered within the initial codes.

I am adding a picture of a chart with the old and new values based on this change.

I should note that I changed something that is not apparent in the sheet as part of this test.  Visually, Line 6 and Line 9 are apparently identical, but they produce different values for both the old and new formulas.  This is because Line 6 has four trailing spaces which affect both the old and new counts.  I had considered using the TRIM function but that function not only removes trailing spaces, but also removes leading spaces and limits intermediate spaces to single spaces.  If the trailing spaces do need to be removed without impacting the rest of the original code, it may make sense to create a Public Function in VBA to invoke its RTrim function.

Remember, there is no checking for duplicates.

[image: Revised Formula]

My last comment above has me concerned because if you truly want unique values and you have a tremendous number of items, you will not necessarily be able to spot places where two things like "John Wayne" and "Wayne John" came up with the same code for dissimilar values.  While I do not have a way to ensure the uniqueness of the codes given how we are assigning them, I thought I would add a way to at least be alerted to them.  By becoming aware of these duplicate assignments, perhaps you can manually address them if they aren't numerous or very common.

I set up a spreadsheet using only the newer formula in Column B and I added a formula in Column C to identify rows where there is another row with the same numeric code but a different original code.  Since upper and lower case are considered the same, this is fairly straightforward.  The formula I used in Column C is:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,"="&B1,A:A,"<>"&A1)>0,"Not Unique","")
```

This produced this third result:

[image: Identifying Potential Errors]

Remember row 6 has 4 additional spaces at the end, so it numerically gets the same sum as Row 12 (where there are two spaces between each word).  Also note that although Row 3 and Row 15 look different, they are considered the same code since it is only a difference of letter case.  Not every cell with "Not Unique" will be a problem.  For example Rows 1, 2, and 10 are all flagged, but Rows 1 and 10 appropriately match; it is just that they do not match Row 2.

Comment: Also it removes the volatile INDIRECT.

Comment: You can just change the SUM to SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: Yes.  I realized that after seeing your formula.  If I wanted to use your formula in this sheet, I would change the Row function to ROW($1:$100) so that it does not keep changing as it is copied down the rows.  The OP doesn't say where the data is, so I did not note that in response to your comment.  I always learn something from your posts and comments.

Comment: What does the -64 do exactly?

Comment: Spaces are very common. Hypothetically, if the order of the characters was an issue, does that mean I wouldn't be able to use sum or sumproduct because it's commutative?

Comment: I was going to mention a few things I would change if I were to use that formula and that is one of them.  One of them would be to change SUM to SUMPRODUCT so it does not need to be an array formula.  Also,  I am treating spaces as a -32 because I am subtracting 64 from each character.  I have no idea what characters you may encounter and do not know if spaces are likely.  The ASCII code for the upper case alphabet starts at 64, so by subtracting 64, I get 1 for A and 2 for B etc since their ASCII codes are 65, 66, etc.  I will update the post with a formula that is a bit more forgiving.

Comment: Actually, I was going to suggest that we treat spaces as zeroes rather than -32.  I have been thinking about it and probably should treat all characters as significant.  If I treated spaces as zeroes, two values differing only in the number of spaces would get the same code.  The revised formula I added tries to add something for every character encountered including spaces.  See the notes I added with the modifications.